# Vector of 2 Different Greek Symbols on Ggplot Grid Label

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I want to place the following in the same order \phi = 0.4, \theta = 0.4 in column 1 \phi = 0.45, \theta = 0.45 in column 2 and \phi = 0.35, \theta = 0.5 in column 3

```
library(reshape2)
set.seed(199)
ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd1_psi0.8 <-  runif(4, min = 0, max = 2)
ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd1_psi0.8 <- runif(4, min = 0, max = 2)
ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd1_psi0.9 <-  runif(4, min = 0, max = 2)
ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd1_psi0.9 <- runif(4, min = 0, max = 2)
ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd1_psi0.95 <-  runif(4, min = 0, max = 2)
ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd1_psi0.95 <- runif(4, min = 0, max = 2)

ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd3_psi0.8 <-  runif(4, min = 2, max = 5)
ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd3_psi0.8 <- runif(4, min = 2, max = 5)
ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd3_psi0.9 <-  runif(4, min = 2, max = 5)
ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd3_psi0.9 <- runif(4, min = 2, max = 5)
ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd3_psi0.95 <-  runif(4, min = 2, max = 5)
ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd3_psi0.95 <- runif(4, min = 2, max = 5)

ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd5_psi0.8 <-  runif(4, min = 5, max = 10)
ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd5_psi0.8 <- runif(4, min = 5, max = 10)
ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd5_psi0.9 <-  runif(4, min = 5, max = 10)
ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd5_psi0.9 <- runif(4, min = 5, max = 10)
ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd5_psi0.95 <-  runif(4, min = 5, max = 10)
ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd5_psi0.95 <- runif(4, min = 5, max = 10)

ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd10_psi0.8 <-  runif(4, min = 10, max = 16)
ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd10_psi0.8 <- runif(4, min = 10, max = 16)
ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd10_psi0.9 <-  runif(4, min = 10, max = 16)
ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd10_psi0.9 <- runif(4, min = 10, max = 16)
ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd10_psi0.95 <-  runif(4, min = 10, max = 16)
ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd10_psi0.95 <- runif(4, min = 10, max = 16)

library(tibble)

ID <- rep(rep(c("10", "15", "20", "25"), 1), 1))
ARMA11_MAE_df1 <- data.frame(ID, ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd1_psi0.8, ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd1_psi0.8, ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd1_psi0.9, ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd1_psi0.9, ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd1_psi0.95, ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd1_psi0.95, ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd3_psi0.8, ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd3_psi0.8, ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd3_psi0.9, ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd3_psi0.9, ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd3_psi0.95, ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd3_psi0.95, ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd5_psi0.8, ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd5_psi0.8, ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd5_psi0.9, ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd5_psi0.9, ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd5_psi0.95, ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd5_psi0.95, ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd10_psi0.8, ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd10_psi0.8, ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd10_psi0.9, ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd10_psi0.9, ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd10_psi0.95, ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd10_psi0.95)

ARMA11_MAE_reshapp1 <- reshape2::melt(ARMA11_MAE_df1, id = "ID")
ARMA11_MAE_reshapp1 <- unique(ARMA11_MAE_reshapp1)

library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

# Instead of using a character vector make your psi column a list column.

ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT <- tibble::tibble(
  MAE = ARMA11_MAE_reshapp1$value,
  year = ARMA11_MAE_reshapp1$ID,
  n = rep(rep(c("10", "15", "20", "25"), each = 1), 24),
  Methods = rep(rep(c("MBB", "MBBR"), each = 4), 12),
  sd = rep(rep(c(1, 3, 5, 10), each = 24), 1),
  psi = rep(rep(list(c(0.5, 0.3), c(0.5, 0.4), c(0.35, 0.6)), each = 8), 4))

ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$sd <- factor(ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$sd, levels = ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$sd, labels = paste("sd ==", ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$sd))
ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$year <- factor(ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$year, levels = ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$year[1:4])
ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$n <- factor(ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$n, levels = ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$n[1:4])

# Create the labels
ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$psi <- purrr::map_chr(ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$psi, function(x) {
  paste(paste0("psi[", seq_along(x), "]==", x), collapse = "*textstyle(',')~", sep = "")
})

ggplot(ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT, aes(x = n, y = MAE, group = Methods)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = Methods)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = Methods)) +
  xlab("Sample Size(n)") +
  ylab("MAE") +
  facet_grid(sd ~ psi, scales = "free_y", labeller = label_parsed) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.0)) +
  theme_bw(14) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -90, vjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = rel(1.00), angle = 0)) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = rel(.55), angle = 90)) +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 12), legend.text = element_text(size = 10))
```

I have [image: this output]

**What I Want**

I what \phi = "", \theta = "" in each column [![like this image][2]][2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to first create separate columns for the `phi` and the `theta` values. Afterwards create the `plotmath` labels via e.g. `paste0`. To get right order of the panels convert the labels column to a factor:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)

ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$phi1 <- purrr::map_dbl(ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$psi, 1)
ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$theta1 <- purrr::map_dbl(ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$psi, 2)

ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$label <- paste0("varphi==", ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$phi1, "*textstyle(',')~", "theta==", ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$theta1)

ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$label <- factor(ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$label, levels = unique(ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$label))

ggplot(ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT, aes(x = n, y = MAE, group = Methods)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = Methods)) +
  geom_line(aes(linetype = Methods)) +
  xlab("Sample Size(n)") +
  ylab("RMSE") +
  ggplot2::facet_grid(sd ~ label, scales = "free_y", labeller = label_parsed) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.0, 0.0)) +
  theme_bw(18) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -90, vjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = rel(1.00), angle = 0)) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = rel(.55), angle = 90)) +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 12), legend.text = element_text(size = 10))
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
library(reshape2)
library(tibble)

set.seed(199)
ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd1_psi0.8 <-  runif(4, min = 0, max = 2)
ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd1_psi0.8 <- runif(4, min = 0, max = 2)
ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd1_psi0.9 <-  runif(4, min = 0, max = 2)
ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd1_psi0.9 <- runif(4, min = 0, max = 2)
ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd1_psi0.95 <-  runif(4, min = 0, max = 2)
ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd1_psi0.95 <- runif(4, min = 0, max = 2)

ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd3_psi0.8 <-  runif(4, min = 2, max = 5)
ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd3_psi0.8 <- runif(4, min = 2, max = 5)
ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd3_psi0.9 <-  runif(4, min = 2, max = 5)
ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd3_psi0.9 <- runif(4, min = 2, max = 5)
ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd3_psi0.95 <-  runif(4, min = 2, max = 5)
ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd3_psi0.95 <- runif(4, min = 2, max = 5)

ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd5_psi0.8 <-  runif(4, min = 5, max = 10)
ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd5_psi0.8 <- runif(4, min = 5, max = 10)
ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd5_psi0.9 <-  runif(4, min = 5, max = 10)
ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd5_psi0.9 <- runif(4, min = 5, max = 10)
ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd5_psi0.95 <-  runif(4, min = 5, max = 10)
ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd5_psi0.95 <- runif(4, min = 5, max = 10)

ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd10_psi0.8 <-  runif(4, min = 10, max = 16)
ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd10_psi0.8 <- runif(4, min = 10, max = 16)
ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd10_psi0.9 <-  runif(4, min = 10, max = 16)
ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd10_psi0.9 <- runif(4, min = 10, max = 16)
ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd10_psi0.95 <-  runif(4, min = 10, max = 16)
ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd10_psi0.95 <- runif(4, min = 10, max = 16)

library(tibble)

ID <- rep(rep(c("10", "15", "20", "25"), 1), 1)
ARMA11_MAE_df1 <- data.frame(ID, ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd1_psi0.8, ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd1_psi0.8, ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd1_psi0.9, ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd1_psi0.9, ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd1_psi0.95, ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd1_psi0.95, ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd3_psi0.8, ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd3_psi0.8, ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd3_psi0.9, ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd3_psi0.9, ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd3_psi0.95, ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd3_psi0.95, ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd5_psi0.8, ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd5_psi0.8, ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd5_psi0.9, ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd5_psi0.9, ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd5_psi0.95, ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd5_psi0.95, ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd10_psi0.8, ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd10_psi0.8, ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd10_psi0.9, ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd10_psi0.9, ARMA11_MAE_MBB_sd10_psi0.95, ARMA11_MAE_MBBR_sd10_psi0.95)

ARMA11_MAE_reshapp1 <- reshape2::melt(ARMA11_MAE_df1, id = "ID")
ARMA11_MAE_reshapp1 <- unique(ARMA11_MAE_reshapp1)

library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

# Instead of using a character vector make your psi column a list column.

ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT <- tibble::tibble(
  MAE = ARMA11_MAE_reshapp1$value,
  year = ARMA11_MAE_reshapp1$ID,
  n = rep(rep(c("10", "15", "20", "25"), each = 1), 24),
  Methods = rep(rep(c("MBB", "MBBR"), each = 4), 12),
  sd = rep(rep(c(1, 3, 5, 10), each = 24), 1),
  psi = rep(rep(list(c(0.5, 0.3), c(0.5, 0.4), c(0.35, 0.6)), each = 8), 4)
)

ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$sd <- factor(ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$sd, levels = ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$sd, labels = paste("sd ==", ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$sd))
ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$year <- factor(ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$year, levels = ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$year[1:4])
ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$n <- factor(ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$n, levels = ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$n[1:4])
```

Comment: (: See my edit. In that case replace `vartheta` by `varphi`.

Comment: please just remove subscrip 1 and subscript 2 and I will be ok

Comment: See my edit. If you deal regularly with math symbols I would suggest to have a look at `?plotmath`. (; E.g. the subscripts could be removed by removing the part in square brackets, i.e. `[1]` and `[2]`.

Comment: The `R code` you `ran` in your `R console` to produce the plot you show here may be different from the `R` code you paste here as your solution. You must have edited the first `R code you put forward here initially.

Comment: This your answer is not reproducible

Comment: Hi Daniel. Yep. Actually I did not realize at first that you changed the name and the the setup of your dataset compared to your previous question. But the real issue is that your question is not reproducible as running your code throws an error `object 'MA2_RMSE_MBB_sd1_theta0.8' not found`. So, instead of blaming me I would suggest to make your example data more minimal and make your question reproducible

Comment: I have changed my entire `R code` to be `MEW`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution by replacing the second part of the label after your function using the `str_replace_all` function from `stringr` package:

```
library(stringr)

# Create the labels
ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$psi <- purrr::map_chr(ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$psi, function(x) {
  paste(paste0("varphi", seq_along(x), "==", x), collapse = "*textstyle(',')~", sep = "")
})

ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$psi <- str_replace_all(ARMA11_MAE_NEWDAT$psi, c(varphi1="varphi ", varphi2 ="theta "))
```

> Note that there is a typo in your labels function, the "varpsi" do not translate to a Greek letter, you can go with "varphi", "psi", "phi", ...

[image]

Comment: I do not need subscripts on the symbols.

Comment: I slightly modified the function to labels to remove the "[ ]" and change the body of the `str_replace_all`, see new graph.